# How to use Inheritance with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am testing a method using `JUnit` API and I think I am setting all the values but still I am getting `NullPointerException`. I don't want to catch this but I don't even expect it since I am setting my values. `l = appConfigDao.getAppConfig();` is the line which throws `exception` and I am using `Mockito` to return `List`. For `getCacheProvider()` I am setting the value using `setter` but while debugging it shows as `null` but I don't get exception.

Method under test:

```
public List<AppConfigTO> getAppConfig(boolean ignoreCache ) {
    List<AppConfigTO> l = null;

    if( !ignoreCache ) {
        if( getCacheProvider() != null ) {
            l = (List<AppConfigTO>)getCacheProvider().getFromCache( CacheConstants.CONFIG_APPCONFIG, CacheConstants.TABLE_CACHE_KEY );
        } 
    }

    if( l == null ) {
        l = appConfigDao.getAppConfig();

        if( !ignoreCache ) {
            if( getCacheProvider() != null ) {
                getCacheProvider().addToCache( CacheConstants.CONFIG_APPCONFIG, CacheConstants.TABLE_CACHE_KEY, l );
            }
        }
    }

    return l;
}
```

JUnit test:

```
private ICacheProvider cacheProvider;
@Test
public void testGetAppConfig() throws Exception {
    AppConfigManager configManager = new AppConfigManager();

    configManager.setCacheProvider(cacheProvider);
    List<AppConfigTO> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Mocking IAppConfigDao
    IAppConfigDao configDao = Mockito.mock(IAppConfigDao.class);
    Mockito.when(configDao.getAppConfig()).thenReturn(list);

    list = configManager.getAppConfig(false);
}
```

This is just a happy path because I want to see if I am setting all the values correctly and then I will cover branch coverage, but if I stop getting exception.

Thanks,

Comment: You aren't setting configDao into the configManager

Comment: Ohhh, it's green now. Thanks Roberto.